# Will slicing a list release memory?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

My python list named `l` contains 100 items.
If I do,

`l = l[25:100]`

Will this release the memory for the first 25 items?

If not, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided there are no other references to `l`, then memory will be released yes.

What happens is:

- `l[25:100]` creates a *new* list object with references to the values from `l` indices 25 through to 100 (exclusive).
- `l` is *rebound* to now refer the new list object.
- The reference count for the old list object formerly bound by `l` is decremented by 1.
- If the reference count dropped to 0, the old list object formerly bound by `l` is deleted and memory is freed.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an option that doesn't allocate a new list: `del l[:25]` will remove the first 25 entries from the existing list, shifting the following ones down. Any other references to `l` will still point to it, but it is altered into a shorter list.

Note that reference semantics also apply to each of the items; they may have references from elsewhere than the list. It is also not guaranteed that they will be freed right away.